# Adding a UIView into cell in UICollectionView,cause flicks

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to add this UIView in a costume cell , and a strange things happens when you scroll, such as duplicating views, the view is changing sizes, moves, and more ..

I have tried to add the view to the costume cell, and also to this method :

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

both results in flicking and strange issues while scrolling down.

I check before i add this view :

```
#define LABEL_TAG 100001

UIView *isstrip = ( UIView*)[self.contentView viewWithTag:LABEL_TAG];
if(!isstrip)
{

    UIView *strip=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height- [Globals sharedGlobals].gridViewStripHeight, self.frame.size.width,
                                                           [Globals sharedGlobals].gridViewStripHeight)];
    strip.tag=LABEL_TAG;
    strip.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    [self.contentView  addSubview:strip];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below  points.

1. Height/Width of the cell is correctly fixed.
2. Your UIView must fit within the cell, check you correctly fixed.

Thanks.

Comment: the height of the cell is not fixed and should not be fixed . . . of course the view is fit to the cell, i can see it and its glitchy

Answer (score 0):

Very easy solution , because the cells are reusable , it means that all cells outside the screen are coming back to be reused , hence if you had some view on them , it will be back .

Solution is the give it a tag , than , check and remove all views with that tag on the cell, before you add them again .

```
for(UIView *view in [cell subviews])
     if(view.tag==1001)
     [view removeFromSuperview];
```

//than add a view with tag 1001 to the cell .